# Conditional sum in R – multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, dplyr, conditional-statements

I'm trying to figure out how to extract some specific information from very big tables (e.g., 30'000 rows and 50 columns).

Imagine I have this data frame:

```
S1 <- c(1,2,1,1,3,1)
S2 <- c(2,1,3,2,1,1)
S3 <- c(1,2,2,1,3,1)
S4 <- c(3,3,4,2,3,1)
S5 <- c(3,2,5,3,2,2)
count <- c(10,5,3,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(count,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5)
```

What I need is to sum the column "count" when, for instance, S1 and S3 shares the same value (it doesn't matter which value), but no other column has the same value.

In this example, it should returns the value 11, because I should only take into consideration the values of the column "count" from the rows 1 and 4.

In the rows 2, 5 and 6, S1 and S3 have a similar value, but I don't want consider them because there are also other columns with the same value. And finally, not considering row 3 simply because S1 and S3 have different values.

I know how to do it easily in excel, but I was wondering how I could do it in R. I've tried somme commands from dplyr, but I failed.

If any of you could give a help, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more complex, but it works. Using only R base. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665929/selecting-rows-based-on-multiple-columns-in-r) take the form of comparing multiple columns in a simple way.

```
sum(df[df$S1==df$S3 & rowSums(sapply(df[,c(3,5,6)],`==`,e2=df$S1)) == 0,1])

[1] 11
```

The most complex part is how to check multiple columns. In this case we use `sapply` to compare the columns `c(3,5,6)` by equality (`'=='`) with S1, (`e2` is the second argument of the `==` function).

As ycw mentions, it can be a little complicated to define all the columns by a vector, so this form allows you to check all the columns except those we don't want.

```
sum(df[df$S1==df$S3 & rowSums(sapply(df[,!(colnames(df) %in% c("count", "S1", "S3"))],`==`,e2=df$S1)) == 0,1])
```

Applying the same procedure to the two comparisons and defining only the vector of the same values:

```
equals <- c("S1", "S3")
not_equals <- !(colnames(df) %in% c("count", equals))

sum(df[rowSums(sapply(df[,equals,drop=FALSE],`==`,e2=df[equals[1]])) == length(equals) &
           rowSums(sapply(df[,not_equals,drop=FALSE],`==`,e2=df[equals[1]])) == 0, 1])
```

Note: Use `drop=FALSE` for selecting only one column of dataframe and avoid "promotion to vector" problem or omit the `,` this way:

```
sum(df[rowSums(sapply(df[equals],`==`,e2=df[equals[1]])) == length(equals) &
           rowSums(sapply(df[not_equals],`==`,e2=df[equals[1]])) == 0, 1])
```

Comment: I am going to give you an upvote because this is a nice base R solution. The only comment I have is it would be great to develop a method to specify columns without knowing the index, such as `c(3, 5, 6)`. When there are many columns to compare, this part could be tedious.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I wish I could give two updates votes, unfortunately I can’t. This is a really nice solution.

Comment: Hi, @Patricio. This is in fact a very useful solution. Thank you very much. I have some cases in which I want to compare three or even more columns. If, for instance, I compare S1, S3 and S5, I can just adapt your command: 


sum(df[df$S1==df$S3 & df$S1==df$S5 & rowSums(sapply(df[,!(colnames(df) %in% c("count", "S1", "S3", "S5"))],==,e2=df$S1)) == 0,1]) 

However, I was wondering if it would be possible to provide, for instance, a vector beforehand and ask the command to compare all of them instead of typing all the possible comparisons by hand.

Comment: I noticed that the commands do not apply for single columns.
If I try, for instance, equals = c("S1"), the commands return 0. (I should have 3). On the other hand, if I try equals = c("S2"), they return 3; but it should return, in fact, 19. Would you know where I could make some adaptations to make the commands to work on multiple as well as on single objects?

Comment: @Luiz, That is indeed the case. The problem is that by default, when only one column of a dataframe is selected, the output is promoted to a vector, when in reality it is assumed that it is still a dataframe. So if that's the case, you have to do something like that: `df[,equals,drop=FALSE]` or `df[,not_equals,drop=FALSE]` Thanks for advice, edited my answer..

Answer (score 4):

Using    `dplyr`, `rowwise`, `filter`  :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(S1==S3 & !S1 %in% c(S2,S4,S5)) %>% 
  pull(count) %>% 
  sum() 
# [1] 11
```

Comment: Thanks, Moody. That is quit elegant as a solution. Even to elegant for my basic knowledge in R. ;)

Comment: Indeed a nice `dplyr` solution, so I gave it an upvote. One comment I have is it would be great to develop a solution without specifying the columns to compare, such as `c(S2,S4,S5)`.

Comment: That would pretty much become your solution wouldn't it :). Kidding aside I thought about it but as I don't know OP's real dataset I was afraid that the rules I'd take (e.g. take everything except count S1 S3 as you did) wouldn't reflect the real situation, so I went for this alternative, less sophisticate than yours but easier to understand.

Comment: Indeed, it would be very interesting to have a more general pipeline. As I said, I have big datasets (hundreds of columns sometimes), and it can become impractical having to type all the columns that I don't want to consider, as in the c(S2,S4,S5). Fortunately, most of my cases, I want to compare only two–six columns; so it was easier to use the solution by ycw because I just needed to type the columns I'm interested in. But anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `dplyr`. There are two steps. The first `filter` function finds rows with `S1 == S3`. The second `filter_at` function checks columns other than `S1`, `S3`, and `count` all are not equal to `S1`, which should be the same as `S3` after the first `filter` function.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  filter(S1 == S3) %>%
  filter_at(vars(-S1, -S3, -count), all_vars(. != S1))
df2
  count S1 S2 S3 S4 S5
1    10  1  2  1  3  3
2     1  1  2  1  2  3
```

Then the total count is as follows.

```
sum(df2$count)
[1] 11
```

Comment: @Luiz I am glad it works. If possible, please accept one of the answers posted here. It does not have to be mine, just pick the one you think is sufficient or you like the most. It will help future readers to know that this question has feasible solutions.